# Using VB.net, how to copy a column from one worksheet in one book to another worksheet in another book?

Tags: excel, vb.net

I've seen this question asked a lot in the context of VBA, but not Visual Basic. In my situation, I must use Visual Basic, and so far I've been unable to get copying columns from one workbook and worksheet to another to workbook and worksheet.

```
    targetWorkBook = target_directory & "\" & "Target.xlsx"
    Set objExcel3 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wb3 = objExcel3.Workbooks.Add 
    Set ws3 = wb3.Worksheets(1) 'Target worksheet
    objExcel3.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs targetWorkBook

    Set objExcel2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wb2 = objExcel2.Workbooks.Open("SourceWorkbook.xls")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets(1) ' Source worksheet
    lastRow = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.count 'Last row of source worksheet

    'Find column by header name in source worksheet
    Set fid = wb2.ws2.Range("A1:Z1").Find("FID")
    'Copy contents in source workbook and worksheet from row 2 to lastRow
    wb2.Worksheets(1).Range(ws2.Cells(2, fid.Column), ws2.Cells(lastRow, fid.Column)).Copy
    'Paste to target column A, row 2 in target workbook and worksheet
    wb3.ws3.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

When I later open the target spreadsheet, I appear to have some kind of reference problem. The data that was copied is actually "embedded", which is not what I want. I'm not sure what else to try, can anyone offer advice?

Comment: `wb2.ws2` looks really weird in `Set fid = wb2.ws2.Range("A1:Z1").Find("FID")`, as does `wb3.ws3` later on.

Comment: Are you sure it's VB.NET, not VB6?

Comment: Well it's probably VB6. I'm new to Visual Basic, so not entirely sure. As for the wb2.ws2 and wb3.ws3, those are short names for Workbook2 and Worksheet2 and Workbook 3 and Worksheet 3 respectively which I set in the lines above.

Comment: Right, but they shouldn't be chained onto each other... should be just `ws2.Range(...)` and `ws3.Range...`, right?

Comment: Yes, this was just one of my experiments to see if further qualifying the worksheet with its workbook would fix the reference problem. With just ws2.Range(...) and ws3.Range(...) I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

What about experimenting with the PasteSpecial parameter xlPasteValues? Maybe this isn't the right one.

I found sample code #3 in this link and there is no parameter xlPasteValues used:
https://software-solutions-online.com/vba-range-copy-method-useful/

```
'copy the range from source book
wkbookSource.Worksheets("Range.Copy").Range("B6:F11").Copy

'paste the data on the target book
wkbookTarget.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: I'm getting Subscript out of Range errors when I try this

Comment: Well, it was just a suggestion. By the way: What do you mean with: embedded in "The data that was copied is actually embedded". So is it right, that actually there are some data copied, but not in the way you want? Maybe you could try another paste option as here described: [Range.PasteSpecial](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial) or the next link [XlPasteType](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype)

Comment: For example, right now, my code is down to this except for the initialization of the target and source workbooks and worksheets per the original post:             ws2.Range("A2:A37").Copy                                         ws3.Range("A2:A37").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues        When I open the target worksheet, I see the values, but they're in an object, not copied into the Range cells, and when I select this object with the mouse, the formula bar says =EMBED("Excel.Sheet.8", ""). Almost like a range object is being embedded instead of the cell values of the range being pasted.